# Real name of view IBM Notes 9

Tags: database, lotus-notes

I am currently trying to track down a problem in another persons agent. The agent crashes when it performs a lookup with a certain view in another database (I do not have designer access to it). In order to see whats wrong I wanted to take a look at the view and see if its empty or not. Problem is that I only have the "real name" of the view and navigation in Notes only gives me the "display name" which is totally different.

I searched the entire client if is possible to navigate to the view by "real name" but I did not find anything. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a properly installed Notes client, and a version of Windows which includes PowerShell, you can do the following after you open a Powershell prompt:

```
$ns = New-Object -COM Lotus.NotesSession
$ns.Initialize()
$db = $ns.GetDatabase("Server", "Filepath")
$db.Views | sort Name | ft Name, Aliases -auto
```

- If the Notes type library is properly installed, you should execute the first command without issues.
- If the client is properly installed and you entered the right password, the Notes session should have been properly initialized.
- If the *server* and *filepath* are correct, the third instruction should execute without issues.
- If all goes well, you will get a sorted list of all the views in the database, with their corresponding aliases (I think you are referring to the alias of a view when you refer to the "real name").

**Edit**: I should clarify that "all the views in the database" only includes the views *that are visible for you*. The database ACL may block you from accessing some views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NotesPeek](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686) tool. It will let you explore everything in the database that you have rights to see, using a tree-style UI.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this two tips will help you:

1. Shortcuts to open also hidden views in the database:

[How to display hidden views in a Notes/Domino database](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091578)

2. Or if point 1. does not help you try to make a toolbar action with the following formula:
   [OpenView @Command](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/c78ce4e936e1fd9685256c54004c295c?OpenDocument)

and then, open the database where you think the view is and run the toolbar action.

If you are not familiar how you can make toolbar action mabye this link will help you:

[Customize toolbar functionality and buttons](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_9.0.1/fram_customize_toolbars_t.html)

Answer (score 0):

You know view's "real name" (= alias).

Create a button or agent somewhere with following LotusScript code:

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Call workspace.OpenDatabase("yourServer", "yourDatabasePath", "yourViewRealName")
```

**or** with following formula:

```
@Command([FileOpenDatabase]; "yourServer" : "yourDatabasePath"; "yourViewRealName")
```

and execute it in Notes Client. It will open the view.

As an **alternative**, copy the database to Local with the option "Application design only" and without option "Access Control List" and explore it in Designer.